# Stuck on Swift coding, stuck on something that must be simple

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create what I thought would be an incredibly simple little app. I basically need it to do some basic spreadsheet math.

In terms of excel I need `=(A1*A2)/1000*(A3)`.

I then need `=(A4-A5)`.

Then the total would equal those two numbers multiplied.

I've attached a screenshot and I hope this makes sense.

[image: screen shot]

Now I know this code is impossible but in my head I need this to work:

```
@IBAction func buttoncalc(_ sender: Any) {
    total.isHidden = false
    let firstValue = Double(text1.text!)
    let secondValue = Double(text2.text!)
    let thirdValue = Double(text3.text!)
    let forthValue = Double(text4.text!)

    if firstValue != nil && secondValue != nil {
        let outputvalue = Double(firstValue! * secondValue!)\1000 * Double(thirdValue - forthValue)

        total.text = "The answer is \(outputvalue)"
    }
}
```

Comment: What result are you seeing?

Comment: What problem are you having with the code you posted? Your question is unclear.

Comment: You have a backslash  instead of a slash in your formula.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time you have a look and help guys, much appreciated although I think I've figured it out. And your right my question wasn't very clear, sorry.

Comment: It's not too late to [edit] your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A text field contains text, which may or may not be convertible to number (such as `abc123`). You need to test if the input fields contain valid numeric values before doing any math:

```
IBAction func buttoncalc(_ sender: Any) {
    if let a1 = Double(text1.text!),
        let a2 = Double(text2.text!),
        let a3 = Double(text3.text!),
        let a5 = Double(text5.text!)
    {
        let a4 = (a1 * a2) / 1000 * a3
        let a6 = a4 - a5

        text4.text = "\(a4)"
        text6.text = "\(a6)"
    }
}
```